# How add border inside div?

Tags: html, css

I'm not good in css , could you please help me to add border inside my div like in image below. I need that border for active image .

[image]

```
.swiper-slide {
border-radius: 0;
user-select: none;
cursor: pointer;

&:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

img {
  width: 178px;
  height: 119px;
}
```

}

Comment: img or background?

Comment: @TemaniAfif image